# How to Create a document preview/view (similar to Dropbox) for my web application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications, preview

How should I start to achieve "**Preview documents from my web application**", so that I don't have to download the document to the computer or install special software to view it. Just open it straight from my web application.?

I want to replicate similar to dropbox, which is very straight, supports most of the file formats(*PDF,Image,doc/docx,txt*) with simple design.

Comment: Show us what you've done in an attempt to solve this problem. Nobody here is going to write the code entirely *for* you (not for free, at least). As it stands now, this question is **way** too broad to fit the Q&A style of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Well I have created - pop which can display stored image files and using apache PDFBox to convert PDF to Image, and preview part of the PDF and displaying it to the user over the web application.

Comment: Show us what you've done! Specifically, paste the relevant parts of your code into the body of your question in order to help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

With [VieweJS](http://viewerjs.org), you have some examples [here](http://viewerjs.org/examples/). If its only for pdf i recommend [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) from Mozilla.

Comment: Looking at some of the examples, I believe it could help me to build What I need.